# Are there any APIs for proximity based geocode filtering

Tags: json, geolocation, coordinates, distance

I have a list of geocodes in latitude longitude format in a mysql db. Are there any free APIs that I can use to filter (using a json file containing the coordinates or any other format) those coordinates to a radius (ex: 1Km) within another given coordinate and get the results back in Json format or any other format that I can work with in C#.

I am aware I can do this manually by using the Haversine formula.

Comment: What's wrong with doing it yourself? Or better yet, use MySQL's [GIS extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) to let you do it via a `SELECT` query?

Comment: @alroc the processing time, because i am trying to use it in an realtime app, Thank You

Comment: So it'll be faster to call an external API? One which may be unavailable or cease to exist entirely at any given time, and makes no assurances about speed or latency?